# Get first N Rows from Database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

My process to get first N rows

1. Get All Data from Database **using Entity Framework**

   `var list = new MyDbContext().Set<EntityName>();`
2. Get First N rows **using C#**

   `var firstNRows = list.Take(N); // N = int`

Suppose,

If N = 2 then I want the first 2 rows of the table but entity give me all rows of the table. Is there any way that entity give me only first N rows from the table not all data from the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `var list = new MyDbContext().Set<EntityName>();` gets no data at all, it returns a `IQueryable<EntityName>` which is just a representation of a query of all rows.

When you do `var firstNRows = list.Take(N);` that also gets no data, that also is a `IQueryable<EntityName>` which is a representation of a query of the first N rows in the database.

You don't actually get data from the database until you do something like a `.ToList()`

```
var firstNRowsList = firstNRows.ToList(); //The database is queried here for the first time.
```

Comment: In other words using `ToList` or other methods that forces the enumeration will load records in memory and `Take(N)` will only return some records but others will not be used. So instead you should use `Take(N)` on the interface `IQuerable<T>` before enumeration.

```csharp
// will fetch only 15 records in memory
var awards = _context.Awards.AsNoTracking().Take(15).ToList()

// will fetch all records in memory and then give you 15
var badQueryAwards = _context.Awards.AsNoTracking().ToList().Take(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var awards = await _context.Awards.AsNoTracking()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(15)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: As you have added `AsNoTracking`, please motivated why.

Comment: @Dejan for better performance. The code only fetches the data and returns without modifying it, so there is no reason for EF Core to track it. Using `AsNoTracking` will improve the performance and there is no reason not to use it.

Also using `AsNoTracking` is good because maybe in the future you'll need to fetch not 15 record but 100'000 and then the performance impact is significant.